# Create an Android Keyboard Dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard

So I would like to know how to create a dictionary, like the english/spanish ones that are included already on the phone. What I want to do is put the english and spanish one together so that users do not have to switch between them, and also add words that are products of combining english and spanish together to make a word. How could I do this? What do I need? And I want to create the dictionary used by the keyboard, not a keyboard.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html

For an example with support for multiple input types and text prediction you can also have a look at the [LatinIME source code.](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/inputmethods/LatinIME.git;a=tree)  The Android SDK also includes a SoftKeyboard sample too.